Equivalence product form of the Gamma function
From the LinesThatConnect video https://youtu.be/v_HeaeUUOnc?si=dUJfeHD9D0O_f5hL we could derive the factorial function
$$
\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} N^x \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{k}{k+x}
$$
and it’s indeed equivalent to $\Gamma(x+1)$ according to wolframAlpha. But I can’t find any way to prove this. Could anyone provide some proof outline or insights?

See Thm. 8.6 here

Thanks a lot! That seems extremely content rich
